# Having issue while counting clicks of view number using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Am having a issue while counting clicks for viewed numbers. Its working but when i refresh the page then also its updating the database and on click its not updating or inserting.
What i want is that when a user clicks on button, it shows the phone numbers and insert the database in increment.
Code below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $('#viewNumber').click(function(showNumber){
                   document.getElementById('showNumber').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('viewNumber').style.display = 'none';

                    <?php
                        $countcheck=0;
                        $checkcounter="SELECT * FROM seo_viewnumber_count WHERE seo_user_id='".$user_id."'";
                        $resultcheckcounter= mysql_query($checkcounter);
                        while($rowcheckcounter= mysql_fetch_array($resultcheckcounter))
                        {
                            $clickcount= $rowcheckcounter['seo_viewmob_count'] + 1;
                            $updatecounter="UPDATE viewnumber_count SET seo_viewmob_count='".$clickcount."' WHERE seo_user_id='".$user_id."'";
                            $resultupdatecounter= mysql_query($updatecounter);

                            $countcheck++;  
                        }

                        if($countcheck==0)
                        {
                            $insertcounter="INSERT INTO viewnumber_count (seo_user_id, seo_viewmob_count) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '1')";
                            $resultinsertcounter= mysql_query($insertcounter);  
                        }
                    ?>
                });
            });
        </script>
<button name="viewnumber" id="viewNumber" onclick="showNumber()" class="btn">View Number</button>
<ul id="showNumber"  style="display:none;">

                    <li><a href="tel:123456" class="home-page-mobile"> 123456</a></li>

                    <li><a href="tel:88888" class="home-page-mobile"> 88888</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a different PHP file for your following code:

```
<?php
$countcheck=0;
$checkcounter="SELECT * FROM seo_viewnumber_count WHERE seo_user_id='".$user_id."'";
$resultcheckcounter= mysql_query($checkcounter);
while($rowcheckcounter= mysql_fetch_array($resultcheckcounter))
{
    $clickcount= $rowcheckcounter['seo_viewmob_count'] + 1;
    $updatecounter="UPDATE viewnumber_count SET seo_viewmob_count='".$clickcount."' WHERE seo_user_id='".$user_id."'";
    $resultupdatecounter= mysql_query($updatecounter);

    $countcheck++;
}

if($countcheck==0)
{
    $insertcounter="INSERT INTO viewnumber_count (seo_user_id, seo_viewmob_count) VALUES ('".$user_id."', '1')";
    $resultinsertcounter= mysql_query($insertcounter);
}
```

Then, call that PHP file by AJAX from your client side code when any click will happen by user on button.

Sample jQuery code for making AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "server.php",
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Counter incremented: ");
});
```